# Trigger que me inserta dato en una columna

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

realice un Tiger para que cada vez que se ingrese un dato realice un calculo y lo almacene en una fila de la misma tabla pero
mi calculo coge datos de la misma tabla y los utiliza como variables al tener una sola fila funciona el calculo pero al tener mas de una sale este error

**mi tabla**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

digamos que el valor a llenar es dias ese dato se obtiene con el trigger

```
    Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

el problema esta en que no se como coger específicamente cada campo del dato insertado y utilizarlo como variable fila a fila insertada

agradezco su ayuda

**mi código**

```
CREATE TRIGGER Meses_calculados
ON Agentes_Ausentismos
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN


DECLARE @Corte_FormatoNum DATE
SET @Corte_FormatoNum =(SELECT Corte_FormatoNum FROM Agentes_Ausentismos)

DECLARE @Fecha_Inicio DATE
SET @Fecha_Inicio =(SELECT Fecha_Inicio FROM Agentes_Ausentismos)

DECLARE @Fecha_Fin DATE
SET @Fecha_Fin =(SELECT Fecha_Fin FROM Agentes_Ausentismos)


DECLARE @Primermes DATE
SET @primermes = Dateadd(month,-2,@Corte_FormatoNum)

DECLARE @Pmfinal DATE 
SET @Pmfinal = eomonth(@Corte_FormatoNum)


DECLARE @Inicial1 DATE
SET @Inicial1 = NULL

if @Fecha_Inicio>@Primermes

SET @Inicial1 = @Fecha_Inicio

else 

SET @Inicial1 =@Primermes;



DECLARE @final1 DATE
SET @final1 = NULL

if @Fecha_Fin<@Pmfinal

SET @final1 =@Fecha_Fin

else 

SET @final1 =@Pmfinal;


DECLARE @MES1 int
SET  @MES1= NULL

If @Inicial1>@final1

SET  @MES1 = 0

else 

SET  @MES1 =datediff(Day,@final1,@inicial1)
INSERT INTO Agentes_Ausentismos (mes1)
VALUES (@MES1)

END
```

Comment: A todos esos select no les falta un where?

Comment: Eso quiero solucionar poder utilizar los datos ingresados para poder utilizarlos como variables si me falta un where como seria  ?? si quiero que me calcule el dato ingresado  gracias por tu comentario

Comment: Tu pregunta es como se llaman los datos recien ingresados para poder usarlos en un trigger?

Comment: si señor  en resumen si

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres insertar una fila prácticamente vacía que tiene solo un dato en una columna? Sería mejor que indicaras la estructura de la tabla y lo que deseas hacer. El trigger está mal diseñado, pero corregirlo solo genera un resultado sin mucha lógica.

Comment: quiero ingresar un dato calculado con el trigger en una fila  cada vez que ingrese un dato o sea el registro ingresado mas el dato calculado  ejem 
id___xxxxxx; nombre_xxxxxxxxx; calculado_xxxxxxxx;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar hacer un UPDATE después del INSERT, cambié el tipo de trigger. También eliminé todo uso de variables que solo limitan la funcionalidad del trigger para que funcione con una sola fila. Ten en cuenta que para hacer UPDATES, necesitas un trigger distinto. Sin embargo, eso depende de la llave primaria de la cual no tengo información.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Meses_calculados
ON Agentes_Ausentismos
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Agentes_Ausentismos (
            Corte_FormatoNum, 
            Num_Identificacion, 
            Concepto, 
            Fecha_Inicio, 
            Fecha_Fin, 
            Dias)
    SELECT  i.Corte_FormatoNum, 
            i.Num_Identificacion, 
            i.Concepto, 
            i.Fecha_Inicio, 
            i.Fecha_Fin,
            CASE WHEN x.Inicial1 > x.Final1
            THEN 0
            ELSE DATEDIFF( DAY, x.Final1, x.Inicial1) END
    FROM inserted i
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT MAX( Fecha_Inicio) AS Inicial,
               MIN( Fecha_Fin ) AS Final
        FROM (VALUES(Fecha_Inicio, Fecha_Fin),
                    (Dateadd(month,-2, Corte_FormatoNum), EOMONTH( Corte_FormatoNum))) x(Fecha_Inicio, Fecha_Fin);

END
```